# How to get the product version from an msi file, without installing the msi?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-installer

I am looking for a C API that gets an msi path, and returns the product version (major and minor), without installing the API.

Thanks,
Eitan

Comment: `without installing the API`..or `msi`, you meant?

Comment: "*... without installing the API.*" shouldn't that read: "*... without installing the MSI.*"?.

Comment: Reading here might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Sounds like [MsiGetFileVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to me.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use the open package thing - this is a static database so `MsiOpenDatabase` and SQL is the way to go. Missing some includes but this works fine:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
UINT GetProperty (MSIHANDLE dbHand, LPCTSTR  propname, LPTSTR strVal)
{
    PMSIHANDLE viewH = NULL;
    WCHAR qry [100] = {0};
    StringCchCat (qry, 100, L"Select `Value` from `Property` where `Property`='" );
    StringCchCat (qry, 100, propname);
    StringCchCat (qry, 100, L"'");
    UINT res = MsiDatabaseOpenView (dbHand, qry, &viewH);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS!=res)
        return res;
    res = MsiViewExecute (viewH, 0); 
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS!=res)
    {
        MsiCloseHandle (viewH);
        return res;
    }
    PMSIHANDLE recH=NULL; 
    res = MsiViewFetch (viewH, &recH); 
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS!=res)
    {
        MsiCloseHandle (viewH);
        return res;
    }
    WCHAR buff [50] = {0}; 
    DWORD dwlen = 50;
    res = MsiRecordGetString (recH, 1, buff, &dwlen);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS!=res)
    {
        MsiCloseHandle (viewH);
        MsiCloseHandle (recH); 
        return res;
    }
    StringCchCopy (strVal, dwlen+1, buff);
    MsiViewClose (viewH);
    MsiCloseHandle (recH); 
    return (ERROR_SUCCESS);

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PMSIHANDLE dbH=NULL;
    UINT res = MsiOpenDatabase (L"C:\\Phil\\MyDD\\Samples Setup\\GetMsiProperty\\Set2.msi", MSIDBOPEN_READONLY, &dbH);
     WCHAR pversion [512] = {0}; 
     res = GetProperty (dbH, L"ProductVersion", pversion); 
    WCHAR ubuff [50] = {0}; 
    res = GetProperty(dbH, L"UpgradeCode", ubuff); 
    WCHAR pbuff [50] = {0}; 
     res = GetProperty(dbH, L"ProductCode", pbuff); 
     WCHAR prodName [512] = {0}; 
     res = GetProperty (dbH, L"ProductName", prodName); 
     WCHAR prodLang [512] = {0}; 
     res = GetProperty (dbH, L"ProductLanguage", prodLang); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and MsiViewFetch() failed with ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS. I suspect that there was a problem already in MsiOpenDatabase(), because it gave me 1 as the database handle (as happened to me before when I tried to use MsiOpenPackage()). Is 1 a legal value for a database handle?

Comment: Database handles are just numbers, nothing wrong with 1. Error no more items implies that there is no ProductVersion in the MSI file. Open it with Orca and look on the Property table. That code works for me every time!

Comment: Thanks, now it works - the problem was that I used INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONMAJOR instead of "ProductVersion". It also works for me now with MsiOpenPackage().

Answer (score 1):

MsiGetFileVersion() reads the version information from normal files (exe, dll, etc), not the product version from the MSI database.

To get the product version from inside an MSI you could use [MsiOpenPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370339(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a handle to the MSI and then call [MsiGetProductProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370133(v=vs.85).aspx) with that handle, asking for the [ProductVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx) property.

```
CoInitialize(NULL);

MSIHANDLE hPackage = NULL;
UINT retVal = MsiOpenPackage(_T("TortoiseSVN-1.8.10.26129-x64-svn-1.8.11.msi"), &hPackage);
if (retVal != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return retVal;
}

TCHAR versionBuf[64] = { 0 };
DWORD versionBufSize = sizeof(versionBuf) / sizeof(versionBuf[0]);

MsiGetProductProperty(hPackage, _T("ProductVersion"), versionBuf, &versionBufSize);

MsiCloseHandle(hPackage);
```

Comment: I called MsiOpenPackage(), and the MSI handle I got was 1; I believe that's ok, because probably handles are given incrementally everytime I call MsiOpenPackage(). Am I right?
However, when I call MsiGetProductProperty(), with INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONMAJOR as the property parameter, I got as a result an empty string. Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried any of the properties from the reference list? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#product_information_properties

Comment: No. I used the INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONMAJOR string, as documented (and worked for me) in MsiGetProductInfo(). I could not understand from the documentation of the properties you gave how should those properties be used - MsiGetProductProperty gets a string (LPCTSTR) as the property parameter - which string should I pass if I want to use the property you mentioned?

Comment: In addition, I am not sure that the handle I get from MsiOpenPackage() is correct, since I tried to run it twice on 2 different msi files (on the same run), and got the same handle for both of the files. Can I verify somehow that the msi handle returned is correct?

Comment: INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONMAJOR, as the name suggests, refers to installed products. It is actually a define for "VersionMajor", which is not a required property stored in the MSI database. I've added a small piece of code to the answer above which for me works and correctly retrieves the version from the test MSI (1.8.26129).

Comment: Good, I actually put ProductVersion in that code example hoping you'd notice :)